# How to disable the particular list item in list-view in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to disable the particular list item in list-view in android?
I mean if once i selected any one of item from a list-view,that item suppose to be disabled which means that item should not be select-able again.
How to do this?

Suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: are you using Custom adapter for listview??

Comment: Then you should save which item is selected and then change view.enable=false. and when you are loading or refreshing listview check one condition that if view item is equal to clicked item then disable it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try using this code in setOnItemClicklistener()

```
if(listview.getChildAt(selectedPosition).isEnabled())
{
    listview.getChildAt(selectedPosition).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 23):

When you pass a list of data elements to `BaseAdapter`, add a field in this list's element class called `isEnabled` and set it to `true`/`false` as needed, then override `isEnabled` method of `BaseAdapter` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

    return list.get(position).isEnabled;
}
```

where `list` is your list of data element objects.

Answer (score 11):

Try overriding `BaseAdapter.isEnabled()` in your adapter, and calling this method from your `onItemClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the item have it set off a boolean.. And what method would use that item have it check to see if the boolean has been triggered, set to false for example. Then in your on click portion use BaseAdapter.isEnabled() = false;

Or with just that boolean alone they can never click it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mlistView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
{
   arg1.setEnabled(false);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable list items on list creation you have to subclass from ArrayAdapter. You have to override the following methods: isEnabled(int position)

```
class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   // return false if position == positionYouWantToDisable
}
```

}

Or in Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listview;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

 arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subjects);

 listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
 listview.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false);
 }
```

}